# How to refresh a list in a filter Extjs on click?

Tags: filter, extjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOqmz.png)I have a column with a filter list inside a panel grid , the list is dynamic based on the table result , I'm trying to update the descriptionsTypeStore and have it reflected on the ui.

```
var gridUserActivities = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
layout: 'fit',
region: 'center',
scrollable: true,
store: userActivitiesStore,
plugins: gridUserActivitiesFilters,
dockedItems: [dockedPagingToolbar],
columns: [

        {
            text: StatusReportForm.LabelDescription,
            filter: {
                type: 'list',
                idField: 'ActivityDescription',
                dataIndex: 'ActivityDescription',
                store: descriptionsTypeStore,
                labelField: 'ActivityDescriptionTranslate',
                sortable: false
            },
            
            dataIndex: 'ActivityDescription',
            minWidth: 100,
            flex: 1,
            sortable: true
        },
       
    ],

});
```

This is my store

```
var descriptionsTypeStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    remoteSort: true,
    model: 'UserDescriptionType',
    autoLoad: function (store) {
        console.log("records", store.data.items);
    }, 
    
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'url',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'rows',
            totalProperty: 'totalCount',
            successProperty: 'success',
            idProperty: 'ActivityDescription'
        },
        extraParams: {
            from: fromField.getValue(),
            to: toField.getValue()
        }
    },
    
    sorters: [{
        property: 'ActivityDescription',
        direction: 'asc'
    }]
});
```

how to update the store and refresh the ui after clicking on a button in another grid ?

Comment: If you call the store's `reload()` method it should update the grid.

Comment: it will update the store of the filter list but not updating the ui @peter

Comment: You mean the contents of `gridUserActivities` is not updated or the `descriptionsTypeStore` which is the filter's valueset?

Comment: descriptionsTypeStore the list is not updating , I need to change the list of the filter based on some conditions

Answer (score 0):

You can create a store that is registered by [Ext JS StoreManager](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.data.StoreManager.html), and use a [chained store](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.data.ChainedStore.html) in your grid's filter value set.

To do so, create the store `descriptionsTypeStore` once somewhere in you application, and assign a `storeId` property to it:

```
var descriptionsTypeStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
  storeId: 'descriptionsTypeStore',
  ...
});
```

From here on, you can get this store from anywhere your application code and reload it using :

```
var store = Ext.getStore('descriptionsTypeStore');
store.reload();
```

Finally in the `filter` definition of the grid column assign it like this:

```
filter: {
  store: {
    type: 'chained',
    source: 'descriptionsTypeStore',
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

(Using a chained store has many advantages, because these are based on the same  source store's data but can have different filters and sorters. For example you can load a complete value set from your server and do local filtering without the need to reload the data.)

Comment: var store = Ext.getStore('descriptionsTypeStore');
store.reload(); is updating the store with the new set of data , but the ui is not updating no matter what I do , I'm expecting once I update the store the ui should also by updating

Comment: what do you mean exactly on 'updating the ui', the filter valueset is not changed?

Comment: yes the valueset is not changing although I reloaded the store and I got the new valueset

Comment: please try to [reconfigure](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html#method-reconfigure) the grid after the value set store is updated, like `gridUserActivities.reconfigure(null, [...])`, in the second parameter add the same column definition which you used when creating the grid